# How to properly parallelize similar tasks in Luigi

Tags: pipeline, data-science, luigi

I spent a good five or six hours the other day trying to parallelize some work in Luigi, based on the method used here: http://rjbaxley.com/posts/2016/03/13/parallel_jobs_in_luigi.html

The problem I was having was that I kept getting a luigi.task_register.TaskClassAmbigiousException which drove me crazy.  Ultimately I threw luigi.auto_namespace(scope=**name**) at the top of my package and everything started working, but I don't know why.  Roughly described, I had 3 tasks:

TaskA - required nothing
        provided a txt file with paths

TaskB - requires only input parameters p1 and p2
        provides a .csv file

TaskC - requires output from task A
        yields one TaskB for each path pair from output A
        is completed when all yielded TaskBs are completed.

If anyone can sketch how i should have done this correctly, instead of the hacked together nonsense I have now, I'd be so very grateful

Comment: Did you solve your problem ?
If not, can you provide your tasks that are failing and how you start them ?
And full exception stack might also help

Answer (score 0):

Did you yield `TaskB` in your `run()` method, or in `requires()`? I ran into this issue when yielding in the `run()` method. It turned out that the task it was yielding was broken for other reasons, but Luigi wasn't very clear about propagating the full exception stack for tasks yielded in `run()`.

To yelp debug, try calling `luigi.build([TaskB])` and seeing if that throws an exception. If you can provide the full exception stack that would be helpful.